# Extract image from PDF in high resolution

Tags: pdf, image-processing

I have a PDF file with an image in it. That PDF was given to me by a coworker and they asked me if I could extract that image, because we need it for a project and we can't find the freelancer that created that PDF.

Is there a way to extract that image, in a really high resolution using a program? If so, which one would you suggest?

Comment: Increasing the resolution does not increase the quality – what is not there, is not there. Apart from that, we do not give [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or [manuals/tutorials](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), but recommend *software* – so if you are looking for software, please read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). Then [edit] your question and adjust it accordingly. Especially missing: what OS should it run on?

Comment: And whether, and how much, you are willing to pay for such software.

Comment: Are you certain that the freelancer created that image. If you think that he may have copied it from somewhere then you can search for it using [TinEye](https://tineye.com/)

Comment: I downloaded adobe photoshop and using the trial version I increased the DPIs which gave me a "cleaner" image. I thank you all for your time.

Comment: Mind to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then, George?

Comment: The title was different from the Q in the text - I submitted an edit to the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`pdfimages`** from the *Xpdf tools* (available from the [site of XpdfReader](https://www.xpdfreader.com/)). It will not convert a whole PDF page to an image, rather it will **extract embedded images** from a PDF.

This is useful if the PDF contains text and images, and you want only the images. Also, it will extract the images in their original format, so no loss of quality is involved (unlike programs which render the whole page and then convert it to e.g. JPEG). Depending on your needs this might be useful.

---

Simple usage:

```
pdfimages -j -list mydocument.pdf mydocument-images
```

This will read the input file `mydocument.pdf`, extract all images and write them to individual files named `mydocument-images-0000.jpg`, `mydocument-images-0001.jpg` etc.

Option `-j` makes it write embedded JPEG-compressed images as JPEG files, not as PBM/PGM/PPM files (which are uncompressed and huge). Note that images may still be written as PBM/PGM/PPM files, if that's how they were stored in the PDF input file.

---

Copied from my [answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/49099/how-do-i-save-an-image-pdf-file-as-an-image/107773)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar problem:

1. I downloaded the 7-day free trial of Adobe Photoshop (in my case it was a one-time thing)
2. I selected [Image > Image Size] and changed the dpi from 96 to 300 (with re-sampling unchecked)
3. Saved my file to a *.tif* format